# chekbox en tabla de usuarios

Tags: php, html, checkbox

tengo una tabla de usuarios que visualiza los usuarios desde la base de datos , a su vez esta tabla le agregue a cada usuarios un checkbox , también tengo aparte los botones de editar y eliminar usuario que salta una ventana modal en cada uno, mi objetivo es que al seleccionar el checkbox de uno de los usuarios yo pueda presionar uno de los botones (editar o eliminar) y que mediante la ventana modal poder realizar la acción , no he podido llegar a la solución de mi problema porque todas las variantes que he visto lo hacen agregando el checkbox en el html , no en la bd
A continuación el código donde inserto los usuarios y el checkbox

```
 <section id="table" style="padding: 6px 0 35px; margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="container  text-center"></div>
  <div class="row g-4 justify-content-center mt-5" style="margin-top: 550px; ;">

    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">Mostrar: </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <select id="num_registros" name="num_registros" class="form-select">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">Registros </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto"></div>

    <div class="col-auto" style="width: 57pxpx;">
      <label for="campo" class="col-form-label">Buscar: </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Realice su búsqueda ingresando cualquier parámetro ">
    </div>

    <div class=" col-auto pe-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-plus-fill" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M720-400v-120H600v-80h120v-120h80v120h120v80H800v120h-80Zm-360-80q-66 0-113-47t-47-113q0-66 47-113t113-47q66 0 113 47t47 113q0 66-47 113t-113 47ZM40-160v-112q0-34 17.5-62.5T104-378q62-31 126-46.5T360-440q66 0 130 15.5T616-378q29 15 46.5 43.5T680-272v112H40Zm80-80h480v-32q0-11-5.5-20T580-306q-54-27-109-40.5T360-360q-56 0-111 13.5T140-306q-9 5-14.5 14t-5.5 20v32Zm240-320q33 0 56.5-23.5T440-640q0-33-23.5-56.5T360-720q-33 0-56.5 23.5T280-640q0 33 23.5 56.5T360-560Zm0-80Zm0 400Z" />
        </svg>

        Agregar Usuario
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto me-sm pe-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editaModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M240-120q-45 0-89-22t-71-58q26 0 53-20.5t27-59.5q0-50 35-85t85-35q50 0 85 35t35 85q0 66-47 113t-113 47Zm0-80q33 0 56.5-23.5T320-280q0-17-11.5-28.5T280-320q-17 0-28.5 11.5T240-280q0 23-5.5 42T220-202q5 2 10 2h10Zm230-160L360-470l358-358q11-11 27.5-11.5T774-828l54 54q12 12 12 28t-12 28L470-360Zm-190 80Z" />
        </svg>
        Editar
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminarModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M280-120q-33 0-56.5-23.5T200-200v-520h-40v-80h200v-40h240v40h200v80h-40v520q0 33-23.5 56.5T680-120H280Zm400-600H280v520h400v-520ZM360-280h80v-360h-80v360Zm160 0h80v-360h-80v360ZM280-720v520-520Z" />
        </svg>
        Eliminar
      </button>



      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">
                Agregar usuario
              </h1>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">



              <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


              <form action="procesar_formulario.php" method="post" id="my-form">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="nombre" class="form-label mt-3 mb-0">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre y apellido" require>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="ueb" class="form-label mt-1 mb-0 ">UEB</label>
                    <select id="ueb" name="ueb" class="form-select" require>
                      <option value="">Elija una UEB</option>
                      <option>Dirección General</option>
                      <option>Dirección Técnica</option>
                      <option>Dirección Comercial </option>
                      <option>Dirección C.Humano </option>
                      <option>Dirección Económica</option>
                      <option>UEB AT&C</option>
                      <option>UEB Softur</option>
                      <option>UEB Datos</option>
                      <option>UEB Logística</option>
                      <option>UEB Varadero</option>
                      <option>UEB CienFuegos</option>
                      <option>UEB Villa Clara</option>
                      <option>UEB Ciego de Ávila</option>
                      <option>UEB Camagüey</option>
                      <option>UEB Holguín</option>
                      <option>UEB Santiago de Cuba</option>
                    </select>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="telefono" class="form-label mt-3 mb-0">Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="Ingresar Número Telefónico" require>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" id="miBoton" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" style="margin-right: 6px;" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3h-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3v3a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-3h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3v-3z" />
                      </svg>Agregar
                    </button>

                    <script>
                      // Verifica si el navegador del usuario tiene configurado un tema claro u oscuro
                      if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
                        // Si el tema es oscuro, cambia el color del icono a oscuro
                        document.getElementById('icon').setAttribute('href', 'assets/img/search_white_24dp.svg');
                      } else {
                        // Si el tema es claro, cambia el color del icono a claro
                        document.getElementById('icon').setAttribute('href', 'assets/img/search.svg');
                      }
                    </script>

                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>

            <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-sm d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table  table-striped table-bordered  table-hover  " style="width: 950px; text-align:center;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">UEB</th>
            <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
            <th scope="col">Selec.Usuario</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="content">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <label id="lbl-total"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 " id="nav-paginacion"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Código PHP

```
    <?php

require  '../Conexion a BD/config.php';

$columns = ['id', 'nombre', 'ueb',   'telefono'];
$table = "campos";
$id = ' id';

$campo = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;

$where = '';

if ($campo != null) {
   $where = "WHERE (";

   $cont = count($columns);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
      $where .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $campo . "%' OR ";
   }
   $where = substr_replace($where, "", -3);
   $where .= ")";
}


// limit
$limit = isset($_POST['registros']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['registros']) : 10;
$pagina = isset($_POST['pagina']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pagina']) : 0;

if (!$pagina) {
   $inicio = 0;
   $pagina = 1;
} else {
   $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $limit;
}

$sLimit = "LIMIT $inicio , $limit";

//consulta
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . implode(", ", $columns) . " 
   FROM $table
   $where 
   $sLimit";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;


// consulta para total de registros filtrados 
$sqlFiltro = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$resFiltro = $conn->query($sqlFiltro);
$row_filtro = $resFiltro->fetch_array();
$totalFiltro = $row_filtro[0];


// consulta para total de registros filtrados 
$sqlTotal = "SELECT count($id) FROM $table ";
$resTotal = $conn->query($sqlTotal);
$row_total = $resTotal->fetch_array();
$totalRegistros = $row_total[0];

//  Mostrar resultados
$output = [];
$output['totalRegistros'] = $totalRegistros;
$output['totalFiltro'] = $totalFiltro;
$output['data'] = '';
$output['paginacion'] = '';


if ($num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
      $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['ueb'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['telefono'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . '<input type="checkbox" id="selector-usuario" name="usuario[]" data-id="">' . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
   }
} else {
   $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
   $output['data'] .= '<td colspan="4">Sin resultado</td>';
   $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
}


if ($output['totalRegistros'] > 0) {
   $totalPaginas = ceil($output['totalRegistros'] / $limit);

   $output['paginacion']  .= '<nav>';
   $output['paginacion']  .= '<ul class="pagination">';

   $numeroInicio = 1;
   if (($pagina - 4) > 1) {
      $numeroInicio = $pagina - 4;
   }
   $numeroFin = $numeroInicio + 9;
   if ($numeroFin > $totalPaginas) {
      $numeroFin = $totalPaginas;
   }


   for ($i = $numeroInicio; $i <= $numeroFin; $i++) {
      if ($pagina == $i) {
         $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class ="page_item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">'  . $i . '</a></li>';
      } else {
         $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class ="page_item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="getData('  . $i . ' )">'  . $i . '</a></li>';
      }
   }


   $output['paginacion']  .= '</ul>';
   $output['paginacion']  .= '</nav>';
}



echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: sigo sin entender el objetivo de el checkbox y de por que tienes la idea de que el checkbox debe agregarce a la base de datos o que espera que haga ese checkbox en el backend php?

Comment: ahora si bien es cierto estas usando el checkbox... los checkbox que no se hayan seleccionado (no tengan el atributo checked) simplemente no llegaran al backend php por eso es que a cada checkbox se le suele colocar un input hiden ejemplo: `<input type="hiden" name="selector-usuario" value="false">` con el valor false o el que decidas que debe llegar por defecto, veras que se elimina el id para evitar la colicion de ids en html y se repite el name para que este sea enviado en lugar del checkbox cuando el checkbox no se ha seleccionado.

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien, ¿lo que quieres es un selector múltiple de eliminar o editar de forma asíncrona? Si eso es a lo que te refieres, se suele hacer mediante JS y HTML ya que el PHP tiene que volver a recargarse continuamente, por ello se suele llevar mediante AJAX y el checkbox suele ser puro visual y no en la base de datos. ¿Puedes proporcionar un poco más de información?

Comment: hola buenas .le comento lo que pasa es que al estar extrayendo los usuarios de mi bd a la tabla, en el html no tiene contenido el tbody ya que se extrae de la bd , al no tener contenido no puedo poner un checkbox a cada usuario con un id diferente para poder hacerle los cambios que necesito o eliminar el usuario , a eso es lo que me refiero

Comment: awantaaaa ... como asi que el tbody esta vacio ... o no estas sacando los datos de la base de datos o tienes algun error de logica en la consulta o algo asi ... que no has mencionado o incluido en tu post... pero no es un comportamiento normal dentro de lo correcto o de los posibles errores.

Comment: el tbodu tiene un id y mediante php le paso los parametros

Comment: y eso donde esta en el codigo??? sigo pensando que hace falta informacion en tu post ...

Comment: voy a agregar el código de la tabla , y tambien todo el codigo php que hace que funcione a ver que si puedes ayudarme

Comment: Listo ahí le dejo el código